# No UI defined (shiny-server )

Tags: html, r, shiny, shiny-server

I've used shiny-server to run my shiny app, and I created the app used index.html file, the problem is that when run the app, shiny-server throws a No UI defined message, so I tried to run the app local and it works fine, but  I found that,  if the app is into "www" directory of shiny server and run with runApp() function I have the same problem (trhow No UI message), but if I run it in sudo mode work fine.

somebody know how can I set privileges sudo to shiny-server?, because I run the server like "sudo shiny-server" but it doesn't work, or can I change location of app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if somebody had this problem, but now I know what is the solution, the problem is not of shiny, is the privileges of user, so you need give privileges to shiny-server dir, with chmod command per terminal, something like this.

```
$ chmod - r 777 shiny-server.
```

that's it. :D